# Repeating a task 100 times

Tags: c++, c, loops

If I want to repeat a task 100 times, is it better to write.

```
for (i = 0; i < 100; ++i) { ... }
```

or

```
for (i = 100; i > 0; --i) { ... }
```

Comment: C or C++? They are very different.

Comment: @WTP: yeah descending loops in C++ make it more like C--

Comment: Well, there is the entirely unimportant micro-optimization of the decrementing translating into something like a `DEC JNZ` sequence, as opposed to a `INC CMP JNE` sequence. But of course if one uses the counter for something (e.g. an array index) other effects will weight in 20 times more. And who is desperate for 3 cycles per loop on 100 iterations anyway, in 2011. This is as much as one syscall or one cache miss.

Comment: @Damon: I laugh at the compiler that fails to spot such a ridiculously simple peephole optimization. And I laugh at everyone using such a stupid compiler if performance is of any interest. I also smirk at people who still measure performance as the sum of an absolute cycle cost per instruction (think pipelines, caches, etc.) and underestimate compilers that rapidly ;) Exceptions for *really* desperate embedded programs that must run on under-powered hardware. But even then, there are much more effective optimizations.

Comment: @Damon: the optimization straw-man. The compiler will work it out anyway.

Comment: @Doron: Did you leave out the type of `i` _on purpose_? (or was this just justifying the 'c' tag as well as 'c++'?) Perhaps this was but a trick question to find out which Stackers would trigger the 'unsigned integer underflow' alarm bells.

Comment: Writing multi-language source files is a hard task. I suggest you stick to only 1 of C or C++.

Comment: The reason why I asked the question is that as Damon pointed out the second one can save an instruction on many platforms. This it does virtually for free, so should one go for the slightly less readable version which may be faster

Comment: @sehe:  Unsigned integers do not underflow.

Comment: @Tomalak: ok, I wasn't aware of a formal definition that says that integer wraparound is not underflow. At least [google's first hit's definition CWE-191](http://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/191.html) very explicitely includes the `0u - 1` case as an example. What definition should I be using, in relation to C/C++?

Comment: @sehe: Nothing normative, but note 46 in the FDIS makes official the common-sense implication that "this implies that unsigned arithmetic does not overflow because a result that cannot be represented by the resulting unsigned integer type is reduced modulo the number that is one greater than the largest value that can be represented by the resulting unsigned integer type." And, anyway, I dispute that the webpage to which you posted an URL indicates that "underflow" is indicated here.

Answer (score 4):

I'd go for #1. It's more intuitive to humans reading your code. In case when no performance benefit can be achieved always choose the more readable solution.

Answer (score 1):

a: `for (i = 0; i < 100; ++i) { ... }`

b: `for (i = 100; i > 0; --i) { ... }`

It doesn't really matter, but I use A.  B should be fine, but if you go to `i >= 0` instead of `i > 0` you get issues if `i` is unsigned.

Comment: It might matter, depending on what's inside the loop. This question is ridiculous.

Comment: Good point on the unsigned integer thing. First tangible argument I've seen

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to use `i` inside the loop, <strike>or the order of execution doesn't matter (no data dependencies between iterations),</strike> then the second one is probably just a tiny bit faster.

But the first is easier for beginning programmers to read.  Depending on who else is likely to look at the code, this might or might not be a concern.

I tend to prefer this:

```
{
    int i = 100;
    do {
        --i;
        ...
    } while (i);
}
```

because it's efficient, terse, and gives the same range for `i` (0 .. 99, descending), unlike the second for loop which gives `i` in the range 1..100 (descending)

Comment: @sehe: Lost the history b/c of ninja edit, but didn't I have `int i = 100; while (i--)` ?

Answer (score 1):

You don't state any use case, so "better" is completely meaningless here.

However, for the sake of sanity, I'll point out this:

It's very unusual that you're just counting to 100 for the sake of it. If you are, then either loop is equivalent to the other.

However, let's consider if you're iterating through an array of 100 elements, and for some reason doing so with indexes. Your index counter should be unsigned, and you should be counting between 0 and 99. Then your second loop should actually be:

```
for (size_t i = 99; i >= 0; --i) { ... }
```

The problem here is that on the "last" iteration, when `i` is 0, decrementing it gives you `std::numeric_limits<size_t>::max()`, which is some really large number. (This is not an underflow: unsigned values are *defined* to wrap-around at the limits of their range.) The loop condition is still satisfied, and you get an infinite loop.

In general, loop backwards to 0 with an unsigned quantity is not going to work as you expect.

Sure, you can work around this by changing the counter to be signed, but you are then restricting the counter's range and, semantically, array indexes *should* be unsigned. Indeed, you're going to see "comparing signed and unsigned values" warnings if you do this.

So, if only in this way, looping backwards *can* be more error-prone than looping forwards.

But, again, without a specific use case, there's no specific advice that anyone can render here. **There is no general concept of "better".**

There's certainly not going to be any inherent, noticeable, useful performance difference in the two.

*It will depend on the contents of the loop body* as to which is the most appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

## Your 2 loops are different!

The first one will loop with `i` ranging from 0 to 99 inclusive;
the second will loop with `i` ranging from 100 down to 1 inclusive.

Comment: It seems like he just wants to do something 100 times. He doesn't appear to care about the absolute counter value inside the loop body.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what is going on in the loop.  If the code in the loop is loop invariant (doesn't depend on the loop variable) then it's quite possible that the compiler you're using will use the decrement version regardless of how you write it.  In general, for readability and code maintenance, I'd recommend using an increasing loop counter.  For performance I'd recommend the decrement version as most CPUs perform better when doing comparisons with 0.

That said, these days with processors and predictive branches/lots of registers it may not matter much how you write it (for measuring performance).  I'd recommend going for readability unless you really really really need to squeeze performance (and even then this is probably not one of the first optimizations I'd target anyway).

Answer (score 0):

Both the same. If 2nd as:-

```
for (int i = 99; i >= 0; --i) { ... }
```

Depends what you want to do in the loop. Generally people count up unless there is  a good reason not to. To count down will confuse other programmers looking at your code.

For example if you are going to be testing array elements and removing them if they satisfy some condition it is best to count down.